# Cancel children object of KendoUI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, draggable

how to cancel drag green div object in bellow example

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/86yTG/3/

html:

```
<div class="drag">
    <div class="not-drag"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.drag').kendoDraggable({
        hint: function(e){
            return e.clone();
        }
    });
});
```

css:

```
.drag{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.not-drag{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;   
}
```

I want some option as cancel option as JQueryUI draggable cancle option

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle

```
 $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ cancel: "p.ui-widget-header" });
```

I try to reset default event of object,but it's failure if ".not-drag" is input, textarea because i can't edit them as default

```
$('.drag').on('mouseenter mouseover mousemove mouseout mouseleave click dblclick change dragstart hold dragend dragcancel drag', '.not-drag', function(e) {
        console.debug(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

or :

```
$('.drag').off('mouseenter mouseover mousemove mouseout mouseleave click dblclick change dragstart hold dragend dragcancel drag', '.not-drag');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it! The problem is that you were calling `e.preventDefault()` which disables input editing. You only need `e.stopPropagation()` to avoid DOM events bubbling to the draggable element. And you only need mousedown and mouseup.

```
$('.drag').on('mousedown mouseup', '.not-drag', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/86yTG/4/